# How to call node api response in socket.io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io

**Scenario:** Creating a Node API (GET) calling that API in socket.io Node server and calling this socket server in angular client.

**What i have done:** Created a node API for get request and post and created a socket server I tried to consume the app.

**Issues:** 1. I tried to consume the API but was unable to get the data in the socket server and 2. If it works, also how can i get the socket data on button click in angular application?

Note: I'm running Node API on 3000 server and running socket server on 3001.

Below is my code

**Node api code runnning on 3000 port:**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()
const port = 3000

let books = [{
    "isbn": "9781593275846",
    "title": "Eloquent JavaScript, Second Edition",
    "author": "Marijn Haverbeke",
    "publish_date": "2014-12-14",
    "publisher": "No Starch Press",
    "numOfPages": 472,
}];

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/book', (req, res) => {
    const book = req.body;

    // output the book to the console for debugging
    console.log(book);
    books.push(book);

    res.send('Book is added to the database');
});

app.get('/book', (req, res) => {
    res.json(books);
});



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Hello world app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

**Socket .io server running on 3001**

```
  var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    
    const apiUrl="http://localhost:3000/book"
    
    
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('getBanners', function(data){
          request.get(apiUrl,function (error, response, body){
              console.log(body)
            socket.emit('result', {res:JSON.parse(body)})
          })
        });
      });
    
    http.listen(3001, function(){
        console.log('listening on *:3001');
    });
```

Note: Node API server --> socketio server (not client)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend going by that design you have.

Unless there is a very specific/important reason to have the socket.io server on a different port than the HTTP server, I would recommend having your socket.io server upgraded from the HTTP server itself.

eg.

In `bin/www`:

```js
const { initSocketIOServer } = require('../socket-server');

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3001');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

const server = http.createServer(app);
initSocketIOServer(server);
```

In `socket.server.js`

```js
module.exports.initSocketServer = (server) => {
  io = require('socket.io')(server);

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('client connected');

    socket.on('getBanners', (event) => {
      // handle getBanners event here
    });
  });
};
```

However, going by your example, if you really need to make a request to the HTTP server to fetch data, you might want to use the HTTP library:

```
socket.on('getBanners', (event) => {
  http.get({
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    path: '/book',
    agent: false  // Create a new agent just for this one request
  }, (res) => {
    // Do stuff with response, eg.
    const socketResponse = processBooks(book);
    socket.emit('result', socketResponse);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any node package for requests like request https://github.com/request/request
[here](https://www.journaldev.com/7995/node-expressjs-socket-io-module)

Comment: that is ok but how can we call in socket.io server and emit it ?

Comment: This may be helpful : https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).